# How to delegate back to the previous veiwcontroller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, delegates

here is my navigation on my app

1) homescreenview controller-->composemessageviewcontroller (i am able to use delegate to send data back to homescreenview)

2)homescreenview controller -->messageslistcontroller(tableview)-->detailmessageviewcontroller(which is where my reply button is).

my problem is when i hit reply i want to send back information to homescreenviewcontroller with delegate . how can i do this?

Thanks in advance.

----UPDATE

@XJones, thanks for the detailed explanaion. is this what is should be doing in when i push detailview? please correct me if i am wrong.

- (void)pushDetailMessageController{
  DetailMessagetController *detailmessage = [[DetailMessagetController alloc] init];
  detailmessage.delegate = self;
  // push messageListController onto navigation controller here
  [detail release];
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's a very general question. you're basically asking how to pass information from one controller to another controller. There are different ways to do that, a protocol (what a delegate generally communicates through) is one of them. The quickest thing you can do w/o making assumptions in your code that may be problematic later would be to pass the homeScreenController along as you push `messageListController` and then `detailMessageController`. You'll need to define an iVar and property in `messageListController` and `detailMessageController` to do this.

Something like:

in `messageListController.h`:

```
#import "HomeScreenController.h"

@interface messageListController : UITableViewController {
    // your iVars
    HomeScreenController *homeScreenController;
@end

@property (nonatomic, assign)    HomeScreenController *    homeScreenController;
```

add the same iVar and property for `homeScreenController` to `detailMessageController`.

in `homeScreenController.h`:

```
- (void)pushMessageListController
{
    MessageListController *messageListController = [[MessageListController alloc] init];
    messageListController.homeScreenController = self;
    // push messageListController onto navigation controller here
    [messageListController release];
}
```

in `messageListController` do the same thing as above when creating and pushing `detailMessageController`. Now, in `detailMessageController` you can send messages directly to `homeScreenController`.

If you want to generalize the above implementation so your controllers aren't specifically knowledgeable about each other then you can define a protocol and pass `homeScreenController` through as a delegate supporting that protocol.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanaion. is this what is should be doing in when i push detailview. please correct me if i am wrong.       - (void)pushDetailMessageController
{
    DetailMessagetController *detailmessage =    [[DetailMessagetController alloc] init];
    detailmessage.delegate = self;
    // push messageListController onto navigation controller here
    [detail release];
}

Comment: No, my example did not use a protocol or define a `delegate` iVar & property. If you use my example, to push a `detailViewController` you would do the same thing I did when pushing the `messageListController`. After alloc/init, set it's `homeScreenController` property to the `homeScreenController` instance that was passed in to `messageListController`.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a method in the messageslistcontroller? I personally would add the delegate "homescreenview" to the detailmessageviewcontroller as the messageslistcontroller doesn't have anything to do with the reply and apperantly the homescreenviewcontroller does.

when you create the detailmessageviewcontroller in the messageslistcontroller do this:

```
detailmessageviewcontroller.homeScreenDelegate = self.delegate;
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach (without delegation)

as you are using `navigationController`, so 
`[[self.navigationController viewControllers]objectAtIndex:0]` will always return you `homeScreenViewController`.....you can use this object....

Thanks,

Comment: if you have direct call then we should not use delegation or notification, it adds overhead to application.

Comment: your answer is fine though it means that controllers will be making assumptions about the object at the root of the navigation stack. For a specific app you can do that. I prefer to implement my classes such that they are encapsulated and easily reusable. That's exactly what protocols (used by delegates) and notifications help do. Your comment is wrong. There is no meaningful overhead added by either method. A delegate is simply a pointer (retained or assigned) and notifications are used extensively in iOS.

Comment: @XJones i tried exactly what you said, i am able to send message to homescreencontroller from detailview. but i still have one warning with this approch. since homescreen object is instance variable in the detailview , when i am sending message to homescreen object, it says "Method xxx not found (return type will default to id)"